# Are Bellatrix's eyes hooded or heavy-lidded?

Tags: harry-potter

Her first mention in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* describes her as a woman with thick, shining dark hair and heavily hooded eyes but in the rest of the series, she is described as a woman with heavy-lidded eyes. Heavy-lidded eyes would mean narrow eyes with heavy eyelids but hooded eyes would mean small eyelids, almost hidden. Is this just a continuity error?

Comment: Do you have direct quotes from the books? That might be helpful to clarify things to make sure you are accurately remembering the details.

Comment: Why couldn't both descriptions be correct?

Comment: Why is this on-topic?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Why not? See also [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11627/100430).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Bellatrix most likely has heavy-lidded eyes.

Though both terms are used to describe Bellatrix’s eyes, it seems far more likely that she’s intended to have heavily-lidded eyes, since that’s how they’re consistently described. Her eyes are only described as “hooded” once and then never again, but are described consistently as “heavily lidded” throughout the series - and both can’t be true descriptors of the same person’s eyes. Therefore, it’s most likely that the use of “hooded” was an anomaly or a mistake, and the intent was that Bellatrix has heavily lidded eyes.

#### “Hooded” is used to describe her eyes only once.

Bellatrix is only ever described as having “hooded” eyes once - at her trial, witnessed through the Pensieve.

> “There was a thickset man who stared blankly up at Crouch, a thinner and more nervous-looking man, whose eyes were darting around the crowd, a woman, with thick, shining dark hair, and heavily hooded eyes, who was sitting in the chained chair as though it were a throne, and a boy in his late teens, who looked nothing short of petrified.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 30 (The Pensieve)*</sup></sub>

Descriptions of notable character traits are usually repeated, and although Bellatrix’s eyes are described again, every other time they’re described as heavily lidded - they’re never described as hooded after this once, before her name is known.

#### “Heavily-lidded” is used consistently.

Since she first appears in the series, Bellatrix is consistently described as having heavily lidded eyes. The first time she’s described as having heavily lidded eyes is at her trial seen through the Pensieve, before her name is known.

> “There was a thickset man who stared blankly up at Crouch, a thinner and more nervous-looking man, whose eyes were darting around the crowd, a woman, with thick, shining dark hair, and heavily hooded eyes, who was sitting in the chained chair as though it were a throne, and a boy in his late teens, who looked nothing short of petrified.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 30 (Pensieve)*</sup></sub>

In Harry’s remembrance of her trial after seeing her name on the Black family tree, her heavily lidded eyes are referenced.

> “He had seen Bellatrix Lestrange inside Dumbledore’s Pensieve, the strange device in which thoughts and memories could be stored: a tall dark woman with heavy-lidded eyes, who had stood at her trial and proclaimed her continuing allegiance to Lord Voldemort, her pride that she had tried to find him after his downfall and her conviction that she would one day be rewarded for her loyalty.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

Her heavily lidded eyes are again mentioned when Harry sees her wanted poster.

> “Their glass might be shattered, but still the little black-and-white people inside them peered up at him haughtily, including – he felt a little jolt in his stomach – the dark, heavy-lidded woman whose trial he had witnessed in Dumbledore’s Pensieve: Bellatrix Lestrange.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 23 (Christmas on the Closed Ward)*</sup></sub>

Then when he looks at it more in depth, her eyes are again described as heavily lidded.

> “She had long, dark hair that looked unkempt and straggly in the picture, though he had seen it sleek, thick and shining. She glared up at him through heavily lidded eyes, an arrogant, disdainful smile playing around her thin mouth.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 25 (The Beetle at Bay)*</sup></sub>

When she goes to Spinner’s End with Narcissa, she’s again described as having heavily lidded eyes.

> “Bellatrix lowered her hood more slowly. Dark as her sister was fair, with heavily lidded eyes and a strong jaw, she did not take her gaze from Snape as she moved to stand behind 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 2 (Spinner’s End)*</sup></sub>

Her heavily lidded eyes are mentioned when she’s at the Death Eater meeting.

> “She sat beside her sister, as unlike her in looks, with her dark hair and heavily lidded eyes, as she was in bearing and demeanour; where Narcissa sat rigid and impassive, Bellatrix leaned towards Voldemort, for mere words could not demonstrate her longing for closeness.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 1 (The Dark Lord Ascending)*</sup></sub>

They’re referenced again when she inspected the prisoners at Malfoy Manor.

> “Bellatrix Lestrange walked slowly around the prisoners, and stopped on Harry’s right, staring at Hermione through her heavily lidded eyes.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)*</sup></sub>

Then when Hermione takes on her appearance using Polyjuice Potion, her heavily lidded eyes are mentioned again.

> “She was taller than he was, her long, black hair rippling down her back, her heavily lidded eyes disdainful as they rested upon him; but then she spoke, and he heard Hermione through Bellatrix’s low voice.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)*</sup></sub>

Since Bellatrix is consistently described as having heavily lidded eyes throughout the series, it seems almost certain that she’s meant to have heavily lidded eyes, not hooded eyes. She’s described as having “heavily lidded” eyes multiple times and “hooded” eyes only once - and the terms are mutually exclusive so it’s not possible for her to have both. [Heavily lidded eyes](https://www.glamour.com/story/what-shape-are-your-eyes-and-h) have larger and more prominent eyelids, while [hooded eyes](https://www.lorealparisusa.com/beauty-magazine/makeup/eye-makeup/hooded-eyes-makeup-tutorial.aspx) have barely visible eyelids. Since the terms are opposites, she can’t have both. It’s unlikely Bellatrix altered her eyelids in the time between the descriptions - when they’re described as “hooded”, it’s at the same trial where she’s described as having heavily lidded eyes as well, and it’s highly unlikely she’d alter them there. Therefore, it seems likely the use of “hooded” was an anomaly, and Bellatrix has heavily lidded eyes.

Answer (score 6):

This is unlikely to be a continuity error, as both descriptions appear within a page of each other in Chapter Thirty of *Goblet of Fire*.

> a woman with thick, shining dark hair and heavily hooded eyes,

> the woman with the heavy-lidded eyes looked up at Crouch and called,

If you are looking for a thorough explanation of the similarities/differences between "heavily hooded" and "heavy-lidded", you will probably get a better answer at [the English Stack Exchange site](https://english.stackexchange.com/).